# bitwise operator use in C++/WinRT CharacteristicProperties()

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

Using C++/WinRT, Bluetooth LE, VS2017, Win10

I have a characteristic in my Bluetooth LE device that is Readable and Writable.

When checking the properties of various characteristics of a service with something like:

```
if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties() == GattCharacteristicProperties::Write)
{
    std::wcout << "IsWriteable = true; ";
}
```

The Read/Write characteristic will not get hit with ::Write and will not get hit with ::Read. The docs say that

> This enumeration supports a bitwise combination of its member values.

So I tried the AND & operator since this is Read AND Write

```
if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties() == (GattCharacteristicProperties::Read & GattCharacteristicProperties::Write))
{
    std::wcout << "IsReadWrite = true; ";
}
```

However, that did not get hit either.  The enumerated value of Read is 2 and of Write is 8 and in Debug this characteristic property showed as "Read | Write (10)". So I used the OR | operator in the snippet above and that hit.

My question is, why would the ::Read not hit and the ::Write not hit but the ::Read OR ::Write hit and the ::Read AND ::Write not hit?

Just kinda curious since this doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic [bit checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

`enum { Flag1 = 2, Flag2 = 8 };`

To check a single bit: `if (x & Flag1) ...`

To check if any of two bits are set: `if (x & (Flag1 | Flag2)) ...`

To check if both bits are set: `if ((x & (Flag1 | Flag2)) == (Flag1 | Flag2)) ...`

The previous check can be rewritten as:

```
auto const bits = Flag1 | Flag2;
if ((x & bits) == bits)...
```

In your case, `Flag1 & Flag2` is always 0 (`2 & 8` is 0).

`x == (Flag1 | Flag2)` only works if `x` does not contain other bits (that are irrelevant flags). `2 | 8` is 10.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that my confusion was the English name to the operators and how I translate that into an English sentence rather than a binary equation. I was thinking, in English, do the properties contain both Read AND Write so I was thinking is the properties == Read & Write.  I see that I need to write this down to be able to see the binary logic that is happening.  Thanks for clearing this up...both of you.  Sorry about opening this can of worms ;-(

Answer (score 0):

That's not how [bitwise logic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) work. When you say `CharacteristicProperties() == (Read & Write)`, that doesn't mean must be equal to `Read` AND `Write`. What it means is to compare the value against the result of performing a bitwise AND on `Read` and `Write`. Those values are `b0010` and `b1000` (in binary notation), and the operation returns the value 0.

What you meant to implement was a check whether both bits are set. That is done by performing a bitwise OR operation on the flags, and compare that result:

```cpp
if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties() == (GattCharacteristicProperties::Read | GattCharacteristicProperties::Write))
{
    std::wcout << "IsReadWrite = true; ";
}
```

This verifies whether properties is exactly equal to the combination of `Read` and `Write` flags.

Although it is more common to check whether those flags are set (possibly in addition to other flags). Using `p`, `r`, and `w` for the properties, read, and write flags, the following expression does that:

```cpp
auto const mask = r | w;
if ((p & mask) == mask) { ... }
```

Another common operation is verifying whether *any* flags of a set of given flags are set, e.g.

```cpp
auto const mask = r | w;
if ((p & mask) != 0) { ... }
```

Comment: CharacteristicProperties() might return other bits as well, your readwrite check is incorrect.

Comment: @and It's not incorrect. It's just less common when using bitflags.

Comment: Of course it is incorrect, what if `CharacteristicProperties()` returns `Read|Write|Notify`? What if a new flag is added in Windows vNext? Checking if it is exactly `Read|Write` is not something you should be teaching.

Comment: @and In that case comparing against `Read|Write` will compare unequal. I'll repeat myself: This isn't incorrect. You are making assumptions here, that may or may not be true.

Comment: It is not incorrect C++ but it makes no sense. If you are writing a wrapper class with a `IsReadableAndWritable()` method you would not do the check that way.

Comment: @and That's just presumptuous. Just because you couldn't think of a use case where comparing for equality would make sense, doesn't mean that there weren't. At any rate, all of that has long been covered in this proposed answer, even before you even mentioning it.

Comment: I made the first comment when your answer only contained the basic `==` check. Telling the OP to perform a strict value check on a bitwise combined value is not the best advice IMHO. `Read|Write|ReliableWrites` is a valid combination but in your mind this does not equal read+write access?

Comment: @and Hardly a matter of opinion, that `r|w != r|w|something_else`. Are you perhaps having trouble distinguishing between `is` and `has`?

Comment: But do you think the OP actually wants `is` or `has`? Calling a varable `IsReadWrite` would not be uncommon even though it technically is a "has" because the other bits that might or might not be set are irrelevant when you just want to know if you can read and write to the device.

Comment: @and SO is a Q&A site. It's not about the OP. It's about answers to questions that are, ideally, useful to *anyone*. Given more than one visitor, there's a non-zero chance that they want either.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a post on CodeProject that helped me see the logic in the bitwise operators.  I was thinking in terms of the C++ && || logic but the CodeProject post had this

The CodeProject table doesn't copy and paste here but it showed:

> A = 0011, B = 0101
> A and B = 0001 (ie what is in both A and B)
> A or B = 0111 (ie what is in both A or B)

I believe this was mentioned in so many words above but this simple table was what my brain needed to see the binary logic.